# Python script to toggle LED's

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sketch, python

I have 8 LED's connected to a shift register on my arduino uno r3. I am trying to write a Python3 script that will prompt a user to select one of the LED's and then prompt to toggle on or off.

Should be pretty basic but I cant seem to get this working.

I have already botched my code trying to get this running:

the jist of my python script is

```
import serial
import os
import time

os.system('clear')

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1431', 9600)

while True:
    led = input("Which LED do you wish to operate? (press x to quit): ")

    if led >= '0' and led <= '7':
        print("Operating LED # %s" % led)
        ser.write(str.encode(led)) # sends the choice of led to arduino'
        on_or_off = input("Do you want to turn it on or off (press 0 for off and 1 for on): ")

        if on_or_off == '0':
            #send command to arduino to turn off the selected LED
            print("Command sent to arduino to turn OFF LED %s" % led)
            ser.write(str.encode(on_or_off))
        elif on_or_off == '1':
            #send command to arduino to turn on the selected LED
            print("Command sent to arduino to turn ON LED %s" % led)
            ser.write(str.encode(on_or_off))
        else:
            print("Please enter 0 or 1 to operate the LED. ")

    elif led == 'x':
        ser.close()
        break
    else:
        continue
```

For some reason Arduino is only dealing with the first input...

HEre is my loop code on the arduino

```
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    led = Serial.read(); // from python script the led to operate
    led = led - '0';
    if(led >= '0' && led <= '7'){
      if(Serial.available() > 0){
        ledState = Serial.read(); // expects the led state next
        ledState = ledState - '0';
        if(ledState == '0'){
          shiftWrite(led,LOW);
        }else if(ledState == '1'){
          shiftWrite(led,HIGH); 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

shiftWrite is a function I wrote because there are 8 LEDS hooked to a shiftRegister

***update:***

I tried the state machine suggestion and it didnt work...

```
  void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()){
    led = Serial.read();
    led = led - '0';
    if(led>= 0 && led <= 7){
      state = 1; //We've received the LED # go to state 1
      Serial.println(led);
      Serial.println(state);
      Serial.println(ledState);
      continue;
    }
    if(state == 1){
      ledState = Serial.read();
      ledState = ledState - '0';
      if(ledState == '0'){
        shiftWrite(led,LOW);
      }else if(ledState == '1'){
        shiftWrite(led,HIGH);
      }
      state = 0; //Ended the operation return to state 0
    }
  }
}
```

With the serial monitor in the arduino IDE open (not running the python script) I tried this input: 4,1

This is my output on the serial monitor:

```
4
1
0
1
1
0
```

Any ideas? Basically the same problem as before...I actually thought the state machine idea would work...

Comment: You actually didn't follow exactly my solution, you're assuming that '0' is 0 and '1' is 1 while in fact, '0' = 48 and '1' = 49. You have to write `if(ledState == 0)` not `'0'`. same for `'1'`

Comment: I'll give that a shot

Comment: void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()){
    led = Serial.read();
    led = led - '0';
    if(led >= 0 && led <= 7){
      state = 1; //We've received the LED # go to state 1
      Serial.println(led);
    }
    if(state == 1){
      ledState = Serial.read();
      ledState = ledState - '0';
      Serial.println(ledState);
      if(ledState == 0){
        shiftWrite(led,LOW);
      }else if(ledState == 1){
        shiftWrite(led,HIGH);
      }
      state = 0; //Ended the operation return to state 0
    }
  }
}

Comment: Entering 4 ... it outputs

4
-49

So it's somehow jumping and setting ledState before I enter anything.

Comment: I figured it out, check your Serial Monitor, you must set it to `No Line Ending`. There is nothing wrong with the code, it's just the Serial Monitor, when you press Enter, it sends another character which makes the loop go crazy.

Comment: It is set no line ending... I was only using the serial monitor to debug...pythons output is doing the same thing

Comment: Post your complete code not only the loop(). It actually worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it is working as intended:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

int state = 0; 
int led;
int ledState;

void loop() {  

  while (Serial.available())
  {
    if (state == 0)
    {

      led = Serial.read() - '0';
      if(led >= 0 && led <= 7)
      {
        state = 1;
        Serial.println("Got LED number: " + String(led)); 
        break;      
      }
    }
    if (state == 1)
    {
        ledState = Serial.read() - '0';
        if(ledState == 0)
        {
          Serial.println("LED n " + String(led) + " is now OFF");
        }
        else if(ledState == 1)
        {
          Serial.println("LED n " + String(led) + " is now ON");
        }
        state = 0;
    }
  }    

}
```

Comment: This makes sense. I haven't tried it against my python code...but breaking from the loop once the LED is chosen should fix my issue.  I will update you tomorrow if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that the microcontroller is going to wait until you choose LED state, which is wrong. Try this:

```
int state = 0; 
int led;
int ledState;

void loop() {  
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    if (state == 0)
    {
      led = Serial.read() - '0';
      if(led >= 0 && led <= 7)
      {
        state = 1; // Here we have got the LED number, go to state 1
        continue; 
      }
    }
    if (state == 1)
    {
        ledState = Serial.read() - '0';
        if(ledState == 0)
        {
          shiftWrite(led,LOW);
        }
        else if(ledState == 1)
        {
          shiftWrite(led,HIGH); 
        }
        state = 0; // Here we ended the operation, return back to state 0
    }
  }    

}
```

You need what we call a state machine, here I use `state=0` for the state corresponding to choosing LED number, `state=1` is for the state that waits for the operation ON/OFF.

Comment: I tried that, but its still not working. To debug I've got the serial monitor on the arduino ide communicating...and printing out what the arduino is receiving... I'll post a response so you can see my code...

Comment: I've updated my post...so you can see the output and new code.